# Why is my for loop not working how I expect to? Run function twice - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So guys, I've got scraping function, where I create object of scraped data. Code of scraper is:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const db = require('../config/db.config');
const Article = db.article;

const prices = new Array();
const ids = new Array();
const descs = new Array();
const links = new Array();
for (p = 1; p < 3; p++) {
  function again() {
    const url = `https://www.olx.ba/pretraga?vrsta=samoprodaja&kategorija=23&sort_order=desc&kanton=9&sacijenom=sacijenom&stranica=${p}`;

    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        let $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
        $('div[class="naslov"] > a').each((i, el) => {
          const id = $(el).attr('href'); // ID, description and link are in the same div class
          const desc = id;
          const link = id;
          descs.push(desc.substring(36)); //Retriving description with substring and push into array
          ids.push(id.substring(27, 35)); //Retriving id with substring and push into array
          links.push(link); //Retriving link and push into array
          for (var i = 0; i < descs.length; i++) {
            descs[i] = descs[i].replace('/', '').replace('-', ' ');
          }
        });
        $('div[class="datum"] > span').each((i, el) => {
          $('span[class="prekrizenacijena"]').remove();
          const price = $(el).text();
          prices.push(price); //Retriving price and push into array
        });
        for (var i = prices.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          if (prices[i] === 'PO DOGOVORU') {
            prices.splice(i, 1);
          }
        }

        async function asy() {
          const sqm = new Array();
          for (k = 0; k < links.length; k++) {
            const res = await axios
              .get(`${links[k]}`)
              .then((result) => {
                let $ = cheerio.load(result.data);
                const pr = $('div[class="df2  "]').first().text();
                sqm.push(pr);
                for (var i = 0; i < sqm.length; i++) {
                  sqm[i] = sqm[i].replace('m2', '');
                }
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                //handle error
                console.log(err);
              });
          }

          const object = ids.map((element, index) => {
            const ppm2 =
              parseFloat(
                prices[index].replace(/\.| ?€$/g, '').replace(',', '.')
              ) / parseFloat(sqm[index]);
            const ppm2final = Math.round(ppm2);
            return {
              id: element,
              price: prices[index],
              descr: descs[index],
              link: links[index],
              sqm: sqm[index],
              ppm2: ppm2final + ' KM',
            };
          });

          console.log(object);
          console.log(Object.keys(object).length);

          /*const ins = await Article.bulkCreate(object)
        .then(console.log('Data added to DB'))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));*/
        }
        asy();
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }
  again();
}
```

Now when I delete first `for` lop and `function again()` and instead of `${p}` in `url` insert eg. 1,2,3 etc. it's working perfect - sqm is fetched for correct link.

Now the problem:
I want to run this url multiple times because `${p}` is number of page on that url. Now first problem I got:

1. sqm isn't correct - sqm data is thrown all over the object and isn't correct for that link.(it's correct when I don't use `${p}`
2. First time i get sqm data(but not correct for that link), when function needs to get ran second time (for second page - to ${p}=2) - sqm isn't fetched at all (it throws NaN).

Also I've got `console.log(Object.keys(object).length);` where I expect first time to be 30, then after is runned second time to I get 60.(each page contains 30 articles), but I get 60, then again 60.

I've tried with many things: async functions, putting axios to await etc. but nothing really work - sometimes I get only 30 articles, sometimes 60 but with incorrect values.

Comment: You must not define a function inside a loop. Move `again()` out and `asy()` outside of `again()`.

Comment: @eventHandler It throws me and error that asy() is not defined. But if i place only again() outside, I only get 30 articles, but correct ones.